# Do you add the destination ticket points even if it was another player who claimed the route?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

What if one player claims a route between two cities before the player who’s got the destination ticket?

Comment: Welcome to B&CG!  This question was asked previously so I've linked it up.  If you have any further questions please ask away.

Answer (score 2):

No, you must complete a route yourself, with your train pieces.

From [the rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_2015_en.pdf):

> Points are lost if **you** do not successfully complete the route given on the Destination Ticket(s) you kept. [emphasis added]

Blocking off a city that a player needs to get to is part of the strategy, if you can figure out where they want to go.